# How to disable NetBIOS resolving in C# (Dns.GetHostEntry)

Tags: c#, windows, dns

as stated in [MSDN - Dns.GetHostEntry Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143990.aspx), *If the DNS query fails, the system may fall back to a NetBIOS name query depending on the configuration of the local computer.* . This is nice thing to know, but I want to disable the NetBios resolving, and there is nothing in MSDN telling what means *depending on the configuration of the local computer*.

Do you know what does this phrase mean (so, where I can find the configuration), or how to disable it somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable NetBIOS programmatically? If not, that's definitely a SF/SU question

Comment: It would indicate, among other things, that this is a computer-wide setting - is your intention to disable this facility for the whole machine, or is it to solve some issue with your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with how the network connections for the PC are setup.

How to reach this differs depending on the version of Windows that the PC is running, but suffice to say NETBIOS is a protocol, in the same way that TCP is. It may or may not be installed on the PC and so may or may not be used to resolve unit names if there isn't a connection to the Domain Name Server.